# Regular expression matching with Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am working on SQL Developer. I want only those records which have non-numeric data. The query I used is:

```
select * from  TBL_NAME where regexp_like (mapping_name,'%[!0-9]%');
```

Strangely this is not working.

Comment: Please give use some data to work with? What the original table, what's the result of the query' what do you want?

Comment: The percent character does not match all characters in the regular expression syntax.  Nor does the bang stand for NOT. Read up on regular expression syntax, it's a whole separate language to get your head in a twist!

Answer (score 1):

How about this? As you said, return values that are NOT numbers.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'abc123' from dual union
  3     select '12345'  from dual union
  4     select 'abc'    from dual union
  5     select '($ff3'  from dual union
  6     select '12.345' from dual
  7    )
  8  select col
  9  from test
 10  where not regexp_like (col, '^\d+|(\.\d+)$');

COL
------
($ff3
abc
abc123

SQL>
```

If there are no decimal values, regular expression is even simpler: `'^\d+$'`

**[EDIT, after sample data have been provided]**

Piece of cake:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'ABC'   from dual union
  3     select 'BCE1'  from dual union
  4     select '2GHY'  from dual union
  5     select 'WE56S' from dual union
  6     select 'TUY'   from dual
  7    )
  8  select col
  9  from test
 10  where not regexp_like (col, '\d');

COL
-----
ABC
TUY

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but  this is not what I want in the output. Lets suppose I have a COL1 as a column and the value are 'ABC','BCE1','2GHY','WE56S','TUY'. Now in the output I want only values which have only alphabets. Output Should be : 'ABC','TUY' .Since these are the only values which dont have any numeric character.

Comment: Well, if you provided your own test case as well as desired output, it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Input Values in COL1 : 'ABC','BCE1','2GHY','WE56S','TUY'  and output should be :  'ABC','TUY'

Comment: It worked ,Thanks alot . Now the question I have is why this is not giving me the expected result :                                                                    
  select * from  TBL_NAME where regexp_like (mapping_name,'%[!0-9]%');

Comment: Because it is wrong? % doesn't do anything in regular expression's REGEXP_LIKE (it is not an *ordinary* LIKE), while "!" doesn't mean "negation", it has no meaning here. Look at the valid patterns, here: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php